# 500 internal server error when accessing a project through localhost on wamp/apache

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, wamp, http-status-code-500

I installed wamp. I wanted to use Apache HTTP server instead, so deleted it. But wasn't sure if i deleted it properly. So I installed Apache HTTP server, and in the bottom right of screen where it shows the time etc, it had the apache symbol, butit was red, which obviously meant it wasnt running. So I clicked on it, and it gave me two options, 1: Apache HTTP Server and 2: WampApache. This confused me as I thought I had deleted Wamp. However I ignored the WampApache and click start on Apache HTTP server. But It wouldn't and just threw errors at me.

1) Why wouldnt it work?
2) Why did it give me the option for wampapache aswell

So I uninstalled Apache and I have re-installed wamp server on my windows 7 machine.
I also have netbeans installed.
 
I put a folder of mine which has some web files in into the www directory in the wamp dir.
I access localhost and it shows the start page with all the text and my projects.
 
I click the folder under my projects and then it just shows a 500 internal server error.

3) What is the potential problem here?

4) How could I fix this?

What I want to do, is make php sites on netbeans, save them to the www folder in relevant folders, open them through localhost, i.e. localhost/testsite and do local development and when they are ready upload them to the internet via ftp.

Bounty will be awarded to the person who can help me get either APACHE HTTP server or Wamp working so I can make sites on netbeans, put them in the www directory and view them via localhost. Preferably Apache HTTP server.

Comment: It's most likely an application error. If it doesn work on another server, it might be because of different lang version.

Comment: If you want an answer, post more information. The cause of the error should be in your look. Look in your Apache configuration to find out where the log is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMP includes Apache, so installing both has apparently caused some confusion and you got both. The sub-folder problem can be a matter of folder permissions.

Optionally, you could try and return to a clean system. This is not required, since Apache is working. But if you wish to try, first uninstall everything, maybe using Revo Uninstaller Freeware, and even maybe do system restore to a time when both were not installed.

Just beware that monkeying with system restore can get one into deep troubles if you or Windows have since installed anything else but WAMP and Apache. I myself try to avoid it if at all possible, even at the cost of a slightly mis-installed product.

You need to use WAMP, since you want to do PHP development, so ensure it is installed and working.

You can use NetBeans to directly work on your local computer files in the www folder of Apache, then test using the browser on localhost. I suggest using Firefox with Firebug for debug. The only complication here are folder permissions.

You can use NetBeans to deploy your application directly to the remote server.
See this article : [Deploying a PHP Application on a Remote Web Server Using the NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/remote-hosting-and-ftp-account.html).

Answer (score 0):

This normally occurs because of a bug in a php script; check that index.php doesn't have any bugs in it. If there's no obvious ones, [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) could help you find it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your Apache configuration the best advice would be to check your error log (see ErrorLog directive in the configuration for it's location) to find out what causes the error 500.